# How to use Spark to copy from XML to SQL Server

Tags: python, xml, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I need to open and copy the content of multiple XML files stored on an Azure Datalake Store into an Azure SQL DB. This is the XML file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FileSummary xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="invoices.xsd">
      <Header>
      <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
      <Description>Hello</Description>
      <ShipDate>20180101</ShipDate>
     </Header>
     <FileInvoices>
      <InvoiceNumber>000000A</InvoiceNumber>
      <InvoiceHeader>
       <InvoiceHeaderDate>201800201</InvoiceHeaderDate>
       <InvoiceHeaderDescription>XYZ</InvoiceHeaderDescription>
      </InvoiceHeader>
      <InvoiceItems>
       <ItemId>000001</ItemId>
       <ItemQuantity>000010</ItemQuantity>
       <ItemPrice>000100</ItemPrice>
      </InvoiceItems>
     </FileInvoices>
     <FileInvoices>
      <InvoiceNumber>000000B</InvoiceNumber>
      <InvoiceHeader>
       <InvoiceHeaderDate>201800301</InvoiceHeaderDate>
       <InvoiceHeaderDescription>ABC</InvoiceHeaderDescription>
      </InvoiceHeader>
      <InvoiceItems>
       <ItemId>000002</ItemId>
       <ItemQuantity>000020</ItemQuantity>
       <ItemPrice>000200</ItemPrice>
      </InvoiceItems>
     </FileInvoices>
</FileSummary>
```

So I used Azure Databricks to mount the Datalake Store as "/mnt/testdata" and then I tried opening the sample file above with the following command

```
dfXml = (sqlContext.read.format("xml") # requires maven library <HyukjinKwon:spark-xml:0.1.1-s_2.11>
         .options(rootTag='FileSummary')
         .load('/mnt/testdata/data/invoices_file1.xml')) 
dfXml.cache()
print ("Number of records in this dataframe: " + str(dfXml.count())) 

dfXml.printSchema()
```

returns the following result:

```
dfXml:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
FileInvoices:array
element:struct
InvoiceHeader:struct
InvoiceHeaderDate:long
InvoiceHeaderDescription:string
InvoiceItems:struct
ItemId:long
ItemPrice:long
ItemQuantity:long
InvoiceNumber:string
Header:struct
Description:string
SequenceNumber:long
ShipDate:long
xmlns:xsi:string
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation:string
Number of records in this dataframe: 1
root
 |-- FileInvoices: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- InvoiceHeader: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- InvoiceHeaderDate: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- InvoiceHeaderDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- InvoiceItems: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ItemId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ItemPrice: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ItemQuantity: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- InvoiceNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Header: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SequenceNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ShipDate: long (nullable = true)
 |-- xmlns:xsi: string (nullable = true)
 |-- xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation: string (nullable = true)
```

So it looks like the command above does read the file correctly and of course I'm able to connect to my well-normalized Azure SQL DB and write records into the specific tables:

```
dfXml.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="dest_table", mode="overwrite", properties=connectionProperties)
```

, however this method requires setting some nested loops and a lot of manual tasks to keep track of each table' keys and respect referential integrity that do not leverage Spark architecture so I'm now wondering if there is the best practice (or pre-built library) which does this task in a more automated and scalable way.

I expect this is a common need so ideally I'd use a library which reads the full XML structure shown at the beginning, and automatically extracts the information to insert into the normalized tables.

Thanks so much for any suggestion.

Mauro

Comment: To parse the data from XML, you can use the `ElementTree` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do and how your table structures looks like. I am assuming that you are trying to process many files using spark. And also want to load the data into different normalized tables

E.g. you may want to write headers into one table, header->fileInvoices are 1 to many relationship, so that could be another table.

- When you read multiple xml file using load(filename*.xml) also you
  want to make the FileSummary as rowtag. Then you will have multiple
  rows in the dataframe one per each filesummary.
- You can select header columns into another dataframe and write that
  to a table.
- FileInvoices are Array of struc, which you can explode them into rows
  and store them into another table.
- Further if each invoice can contain multiple items you can do another
  explode to make them into rows and store them into another table

Or you can do two explodes and load the resulting dataframe to one big denormalized table.

Here is an article on how explode works
https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/how-to-handle-nested-dataarray-of-structures-or-multiple-explodes-in-sparkscala-and-pyspark/

Answer (score 0):

I am using spark-shell to execute below.I believe the xml structure is repeating itself.
You need to create/refer one schema related to xml file.
And you could make use of brickhouse udf jar.
then

1.Create a function as below

`sql(""" create temporary function numeric_range as brickhouse.udf.collect.NumericRange""")`

2.Use the schema

```
var df=sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","FileSummary").load("location of schema file")

val schema=df.schema
```

3.`var df1=sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","FileSummary").schema(schema).load("location of actual xml file")`

```
df1.registerTempTable("XML_Data")
```

4.You need to flatten the FileInvoices as below

```
val df2=sql("select array_index(FileInvoices,n) as FileInvoices from XML_Data lateral view numeric_range(size(FileInvoices))n1 as n""").registerTempTable("xmlData2")
```

Once every gets converted to Struct it is easier to traverse or use **explode** using `FileInvoices.InvoiceHeader.InvoiceHeaderDate`

```
val jdbcUsername = "<username>"
val jdbcPassword = "<password>"
val jdbcHostname = "<hostname>" //typically, this is in the form or servername.database.windows.net
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase ="<database>"

val jdbc_url = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=60;"

val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")

spark.table("").write.jdbc(jdbc_url, "xmlData2", connectionProperties)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Subash, Anand.
Concerning Subash's answer, I don't have the schema file so I modified his step2 replacing "location of actual xml file" with "location of actual xml file" and it actually works: after step3 if I simply run

```
df2=sql("select * from XML_Data")
```

and then I run

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df3=df2.withColumn("FileInvoices", explode(df2.FileInvoices))
display(df3)
```

As a result, it replicates the same single struct of Header across multiple rows, where in column FileInvoices I have a single distinct structure of invoices:
[exploded FileInvoices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84pzm.jpg)

So it looks like I'm getting closer to my final target, however I still miss to automate the creation of records in the right order to avoid breaking referential integrity.

But before doing that I'd appreciate your feedback.

Thanks again,

Mauro